# Вам данно N-ое количество цифр и нужно проверить какие из них простые

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
пример ввода:
3      #цифры
11
1
4
пример вывода:
YES
NO
NO
```

```
def prostChislo(a):
   b = 2
   while a % b != 0:
       b += 1
   return b == a
n = int(input())
for range1 in range(n):
   a = int(input())
   if a == 1:
       print("NO")
   elif prostChislo(a) is True:
       print("YES")
   else:
       print("NO")
```

это мой код но когда запускаешь на hackerrank выдаёт ошибку что слишком долго

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Что именно не получается. получить числа на вход? проверить число простоту?

Comment: я отредактировал код

Comment: можно ссылку на проверяющую систему?

Comment: @Danis это сайт, там нужно регистрироваться на нём наши задания для того чтобы защитали python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ваш вывод не соответствует вашему примеру.
2. Прогонять для проверки на простоту нужно не все числа подряд, а от `2` до `sqrt(n)+1`, но есть хитрость, которая позволяет сделать прогон от `3` до `sqrt(n)+1` с шагом `2`.

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n == 1: # если число == 1 - не простое
        return False
    if n == 2: # если число == 2 - простое
        return True
    if not n % 2: # если число делится на 2 - не простое
        return False
    for i in range(3, int(n**.5)+1, 2):
        if not n%i:
            return False
    return True

nums = [int(input()) for i in range(int(input()))]
for num in nums:
    print('YES' if is_prime(num) else 'NO')
```

Comment: спасибо большое, только с твоим кодом прошло, а то я уже миллион перепробовал

Answer (score 2):

судя по вашему примеру - сначала идет ввод, а затем вывод

в вашем примере вывод идет после каждого ввода, т.е. так:

```
3      #цифры
11
YES
1
NO
4
NO
```

так и должно быть? или результат надо накопить и потом выдать одной портянкой?

Comment: так и надо чтобы выводило как в примере вывода

Comment: тогда вам сначала надо накопить в список ответы YES/NO и только потом их вывести

Comment: так они должны выводиться через энтер

Comment: ну да - они вводятся и вы тут же после каждого ввода выдаете вердикт, а пример выглядит как будто происходит так: `arr = [int(input()) in range(int(input())]` - т.е. сначала получаем список всех введенных чисел и потом только с ним работаем

Answer (score 1):

Перебирать все числа не надо, можно перебирать от`2` до `sqrt(a)`

```
def prostChislo(a):
   for b in range(2, int(a ** .5) + 1):
       if a % b == 0:
           return False
   return True
```

Comment: всё равно на части тест кейсов пишет рантайм эрор